# Copying Members from class list to string list in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists

```
List<Country> list1;
List<string> list2;


public class Country 
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to copy member "Name" to list2, how do I do that?

Comment: 1. Sorry im new, ill try to be more detailed the next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Country {
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

// In using method ...
{
    List<Country> list1 = // assign countries

    // Either 
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    list1.Select(c => c.name).ForEach(list2.Add);

    // OR
    var list2 = list1.Select(c => c.name).ToList();
}
```

[Here is a tutorial about LINQ](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/Linq/Lesson01)

> Answer to comment about "c":
>
> Linq makes heavy use of ["Lambda-Expressions"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and the "c" stands for every member of
> the List (and more generically of the Enumeration). On the right side of the function operator you can have
> either an Expression, an anonymous method or a delegate. The variable
> name is free to choose, it could have been "country", "x" or whatever
> you want. I just usually take the first letter of the class-name.

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way that wasn't mentioned.
You can use the [`List<T>` class constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var names = new List<string>(list1.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you should change your class and make `Name` field as public:

```
public class Country
{
   public string id { get; private set; }
   public string name { get; private set; }
}
```

To create list of names you should use [LINQ and select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Bb397927.aspx) clause:

```
list2 = list1.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```